# Why are unsigned integers converted to a string prepended with "3" in their byte array form?

Tags: string, go, byte, solidity

If I [do](https://play.golang.org/p/n1vEK8SXCss) the following in golang:

```
data := []byte{}
data = append(data, '1')
data = append(data, '2')

fmt.Printf("%d\n", len(data))
fmt.Printf("%x\n", fmt.Sprintf("%d", len(data)))
```

I get 2 and 32, respectively, instead of just 2 on both lines (obviously the array has only two elements).

If I [do](https://ethfiddle.com/7zPTB0Dzef) something similar-ish in solidity:

```
bytes memory encodedPack = abi.encodePacked(prefix, length, signedMessage)
```

The `encodePacked` function also prepends the length with 3 in the final byte array.

According to the ASCII table, 3 represents "end of text". Is this what this 3 is for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Sprintf()` returns a string. You are printing the string "2" which in ASCII is `0x32`.

The 3 here is not end-of-text. If you look at the ASCII table, you will notice that the characters "0" to "9" are encoded as `0x30` until `0x39`.